# Not able to run `npm install && npm run dev in Laravel 7 to use Bootstrap

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7 on my windows 10 machine. While try to use Bootstrap, after executed the command `php artisan ui bootstrap`, i got the blow message.

> Bootstrap scaffolding installed successfully.
> Please run "npm install && npm run dev" to compile your fresh scaffolding.

When run `npm install && npm run dev`, i got the error:

> The token && is not a valid separator in this version.

What should I do now? I've already installed node.js and even enabled the path in environment variable.

Appreciate if someone could help on this!

Comment: Try running the two commands separately. First `npm install` then `npm run dev`

Comment: I've used two separate commands.. Thank u @AndreaOlivato..

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `Powershell`. Three alternatives you have:

1. Try to use `CMD` or `Gitbash`.
2. you can use try this command:

   (npm run build) -and (node ./dist/main.js)
3. Run them separetly. `npm install` and `npm run dev`

Comment: Yes, because of using `PowerShell`, it happened. And, now used the third option. Thanks